# Event Tracking - Web Tracking (ga.js) not working on Mobile

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am trying to capture an event when the user clicks a link on my website. 
I have added the tracking code at start of `<body>` tag

```
<script>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-64301593-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

and then I am using

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'landing_page', 'i_am_interested_click']);
```

on the `<a>` tag where I want to track an event.

It is working perfectly fine for all browsers on Desktop and I am able to see the events on Google Analytics Realtime -> Events tab. However same thing does not work for any browsers on mobile (I have tried Chrome and Firefox).

I have another hyper-link on the same page where I am tracking another event, this time by creating a jquery listener for the on-click event. However, that also does not work for mobile browsers (works on Desktop browsers).
The jquery code is as below:

```
$("#contact_me_button").click(function(){      
      $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).html("<a href='tel:+918695707070'>+918695707070</a>");
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });
      fbq('track', 'Lead');
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'landing_page', 'call_attempted']);
  });
```

Need help as I am new to this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: did you tried developers samples about Analytics API and get solution? what is **fbq('track', 'Lead')** ?

Comment: _I have added the tracking code at start of <body> tag_ The tracking code should be within the `<head>` tag. Having it in the `body` may be tripping up the mobile browsers.